# Bootstrap js with kendo Conflicting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am creating a project using Javascript. In my project i am using kendo with bootstrap. The Problem some of the kendo and bootstrap are conflicting.I know there is `$.noconflict`, But this create me lot of problems. Mainly the kendodropdown is conflicting.

```
<!-- Mainly scripts -->
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
            <script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()/js/custom.js?v=$version"></script>
```

If I remove the bootstrap file then kendo functions working properly.Please help me for using  kendo and bootstrap together.

The exact issue is when i open dropdown and scrolls it automatically closes.

This is the code:

```
 $("#searchTktID").kendoDropDownList({
         filter: "startswith",

     });
```

and am handling this situation using

```
 close: function(e){
                if(isScroll) {
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                    }
             },
             open:function(){
                 isScroll = true;
             },
```

But this is not correct way i think.

Comment: In what way it is conflicting? I have been using the two together for years with little to no problems at all. have you looked at this link on how Telerik recommend 3rd party integration https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I am using the js file of bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your exact problem it sounds like it may be a script ordering problem.

For example this is how I include the scripts in my projects for kendo and bootstrap integrated MVC apps.

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-switch.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2019.2.514/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2019.2.514/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2019.2.514/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2019.2.514/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2019.2.514/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2019.2.514/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/umd/popper.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fa")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Custom")
```

As long as you ensure that the `bootstrap.js` file is loaded after the `kendo.js` files you should be good.

As I said in my comment I have been using this approach for both version `3.x` and `4.x`

Edit: Please see a this dojo with bootstrap and kendo libraries working together. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/AkIBOjOr/2

One thing to check is that you aren't reloading JQuery after you have loaded the kendo js files as that will show the kendoDropDownList is not a function error.

Edit 2: I have added filtering on the cap colour dropdown list.

Comment: I have added a dojo showing both libraries working together

Comment: @DavidShorthose just curious why not bundle all?

Comment: From memory the bundling does bundling based on alphabetical ordering. Plus doing it this way when I need to update the kendo scripts I simply have to change the folder name if the upgrade wizard doesn’t already do it for me. In addition I think when I first started using the kendo vs template it loads the scripts this way so just left it like this (if it isn’t broke don’t fix it)

Comment: @DavidShorthose you can also give your own order in your bundle. Explicitly adding each file to a bundle is generally the preferred over wildcard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh195144(v=vs.110)

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the downsides of Kendo, you will need to customize your controls to look the way you would like. Kendo override your base bootstrap css, and mainly on the controls like dropDown, comboBox, autoComplete they are quite problematic. One solution is to use the [telerik theme builder](https://themebuilder.telerik.com/)

You are able to customize your controls and download the CSS files. Other solution will be choosing a different theme from the bootstrap theme but **both solutions need to override your css** to get the final design you intend.

[general documentation for setup a theme](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling)